# How does the B-2 Spirit fly without a rudder?

Tags: aerodynamics, rudder, b-2

On the B-2 Spirit bomber there are no rudders on the back of the aircraft, how does it fly without entering a flat spin or losing control, because when other aircraft like commercial liners lose their rudders it usually ends in a crash?

[image: B2 Spirit]

Comment: Birds have no rudders, and fly quite well...

Comment: If you _must_ have an image in your post, please attribute it. In this case, the B-2 is one of the best-known modern airframe designs so it's debatable whether you really need a photo at all.

Comment: It uses a fly-by-wire system to actively maintain stability, and uses split ailerons at the wing tips for differential drag for yaw control.